# Start date returns in some cases when using google-rfc-2445 (iCalendar)

Tags: java, icalendar, rfc2445

I ran through a lot of RRULEs just for testing out the performance of [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) (a Java implementation of [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445) [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)).

I saw that I got the start date back in some cases in the returning list from the method.

The test is very simple:

```
private static void runGoogleTests() throws ParseException
{
    DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.UTC;
    DateTime dtStart = new DateTime("2014-11-22T00:00:00Z", dtz);//SATURDAY
    DateTimeIterable dti = DateTimeIteratorFactory.createDateTimeIterable("RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;BYDAY=MO", dtStart, dtz, true);

    System.out.println("Size of iterable = " + Iterators.size(dti.iterator()));
    for(DateTime dateTime : dti)
    {
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```

The list returned by the factory returns this list.

The first date is the start date and it's a saturday that should not be there. The RRULE also contained a COUNT=10 so why return 11?

```
Size of iterable = 11
2014-11-22T00:00:00.000Z
2014-11-24T00:00:00.000Z
2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
2014-12-08T00:00:00.000Z
2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
2014-12-22T00:00:00.000Z
2014-12-29T00:00:00.000Z
2015-01-05T00:00:00.000Z
2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z
2015-01-19T00:00:00.000Z
2015-01-26T00:00:00.000Z
```

Someone using the Google-rfc-2445 must have encountered this problem before?

I posted the issue on the projects page but it's very quiet there.
[Link to the issue on google-rfc-2445 page](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/issues/detail?id=12)

Answer (score 3):

[RFC2445 section 4.3.10 Recurrence Rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#page-40) specifies that

> [...] The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which to range-bound the recurrence. The "DTSTART" property value, if specified, counts as the first occurrence. [...]

so while the presence of the `DTSTART` in the returned list is normal, what is less expected is the size of the returned list.

Given the RFC2445 specification, it makes more sense to have the `DTSTART` being the first instance of the recurrence to also insure that other calendars understand the ical file properly.

Also to be noted `RFC2445` is obsoleted by `RFC5545` which also specifies the `DTSTART` as the first instance of the `RRULE` (and even emphasizes it, note: the added word ***always*** (empahsis added by me)

> [RFC5545 RRULE section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10): The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which to       range-bound the recurrence.  The "DTSTART" property value ***always*** counts as the first occurrence.

Comment: I came here due to same issue as topic starter, and your answer at first helped me but after I've found a rrule.js library it confused me even more. If I use this RRULE string `FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;BYDAY=MO;DTSTART=20150301` here: http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/ it gives me exactly 10 occurrences and not count **DTSTART** as first occurence, who is wrong? May it be that rrule.js implemented not correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public static DateTimeIterator createDateTimeIterator(
        final String repeatRules,
        final DateTime scheduleStart,
        final DateTimeZone timeZone) throws ParseException {

    DateTime start = scheduleStart;
    String exdate = "";
    final RRule rrule = new RRule(repeatRules);
    if (rrule.getFreq().ordinal() > Frequency.DAILY.ordinal()) {
        start = start.minusDays(1);
        exdate = "\nEXDATE:"
                + ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis().print(start.withZone(timeZone).toLocalDateTime());
    }

    final DateTimeIterable dateIterable = DateTimeIteratorFactory.createDateTimeIterable(
            repeatRules + exdate,
            start,
            timeZone,
            true);

    return dateIterable.iterator();

}
```

The idea is to start the sequence one day earlier and to exclude the first date by using EXDATE rule.