# rfc 2445, rfc 5545 vs rrule.js, should DTSTART be counted as a first occurence or shouldn't?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445, rrule

Recently I began to work with [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) library and met a same problem as SO user **Art Zaborskiy** here: [Start date returns in some cases when using google-rfc-2445 (iCalendar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486705/start-date-returns-in-some-cases-when-using-google-rfc-2445-icalendar) 
After SO user **oberron** pointed to specification in him answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659453/947111), where being said that:

> [...] The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which
>   to range-bound the recurrence. The "DTSTART" property value, if
>   specified, counts as the first occurrence. [...]

I was sure that my issue is over, and it isn't issue but feature. I thought so till I found [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) libary here, in its [demo page](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/) it returns exactly 10 occurrences without **DTSTART** occurrence, while same **RRULE String** in **google-rfc-2445** return 11 occurrences. 
The **RRULE String** is following: `FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;BYDAY=MO;DTSTART=20150301`

Now I totally confused, should or shouldn't **DTSTART** occurrence be in a list of all occurrences? 
Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Looks like [someone opened an issue with rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/issues/84) regarding DTSTART.  The RFC should probably be considered the standard, not a specific implementation of it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, thank you for pointing me to this, now I relaxed :)