# end date(UNTIL) is excluded when using google-rfc-2445 createDateTimeIterator to generate date range

Tags: java, icalendar, rfc2445

I need to know how do i avoid UNTIL or end date getting excluded in the date range being created in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628608/5311573

Please help.

I'm trying to get the date range using the answer given in above link but it excludes the end date every time.

```
StartDate = 2020-04-21T00:00:00.000+05:30;
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20200428
```

it will return me below result:

```
2020-04-20T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-21T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-22T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-23T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-24T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-25T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-26T18:30:00.000Z
2020-04-27T18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: There is also time in your result code, do you use `StartDate` with time also as `2020-04-21T18:30:00.000Z` and forgot to put it in your example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start date and time appears to be 
2020-04-20T18:30:00.000Z
despite your pseudo code above.  Because that is what you have listed as your results: recurrences at 18.30.

With a daily recurrence at those times, 2020-04-28T18:30:00.000Z would be AFTER 2020-04-20T00:00:000Z.

So make the start date or datetime and end date or datetime consistent. From https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-10-recurrence-rule.html, it says:

> The UNTIL rule part defines a DATE or DATE-TIME value that bounds the
>   recurrence rule in an inclusive manner. If the value specified by
>   UNTIL is synchronized with the specified recurrence, this DATE or
>   DATE-TIME becomes the last instance of the recurrence. The value of
>   the UNTIL rule part MUST have the same value type as the "DTSTART"
>   property. Furthermore, if the "DTSTART" property is specified as a
>   date with local time, then the UNTIL rule part MUST also be specified
>   as a date with local time. If the "DTSTART" property is specified as a
>   date with UTC time or a date with local time and time zone reference,
>   then the UNTIL rule part MUST be specified as a date with UTC time.

change UNTIL to 2020-04-28T18:30:00.000Z if UTC time intended or 
2020-04-28T18:30:00.000 if floating time intended.
Basically DTSTART And UNTIL must match.